# How to merge two VBA codes in one?

Tags: excel, vba

I have these two VBA codes, to get the result i want, i have to put the following excel formula to do the trick:

```
=CCPA(A1)&(MAJUSCULE(A1&MAJUSCULE(RIP(A1))))
```

I want to merge the two together in a function named for example : Account, so by just typing =Account(A1), it will give me the result obtained from the formula :

```
=CCPA(A1) & (MAJUSCULE( A1 & MAJUSCULE( RIP ( A1 ) ) ) ).
```

The codes are :

```
Function CCPA(X)
    Select Case Len(X)
        Case 0
            c1 = "00799999000000000"
        Case 1
            c1 = "00799999000000000"
        Case 2
            c1 = "0079999900000000"
        Case 3
            c1 = "007999990000000"
        Case 4
            c1 = "00799999000000"
        Case 5
            c1 = "0079999900000"
        Case 6
            c1 = "007999990000"
        Case 7
            c1 = "00799999000"
        Case 8
            c1 = "0079999900"
        Case 9
            c1 = "007999990"
        Case 10
            c1 = "00799999"
    End Select
    CCPA = c1   
End Function

Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String
  Cle_RIP = Right(Cle_RIP, 10)
  If Cle_RIP = "" Then
      Cle_RIP = 0
  End If
  RIP = Cle_RIP * 100
  RIP = RIP - 97 * Int(RIP / 97)
  RIP = RIP + 85
  
  If RIP < 97 Then
      RIP = RIP + 97
  Else
      RIP = RIP
  End If
  
  RIP = RIP - 97
  RIP = 97 - RIP
  
  If RIP < 10 Then
      RIP = "0" & RIP
  Else
      RIP = RIP
  End If
End Function
```

Thanks In advance (I have also posted this on superuser forums). I don't know if it's inter related with this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function

```
Public Function BOTH(X)
    BOTH = CCPA(X) & UCase$(X & UCase$(RIP(CStr(X))))
End Function
```

of course you can name it as you like